# Rayleigh distance of array antenna

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, antenna-array, far-field

Far field zone of a single antenna can be determined by using the equation below.

$$R>\dfrac{2D^2}{\lambda}$$

Where D is the biggest dimension of the antenna.

This equaiton is suitable for single antenna. But what if there are more antennas than one?

How can we determine rayleigh distance, far-field distance, of an array antenna?
For example, how can I determine far-field distance of an two element (aperture type antennas) linear array antenna as shown below?

[image]

Comment: The far-field region is \$> \dfrac{2D^2}{\lambda}\$. It doesn't equal it.

Comment: I edited it @Andyaka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is still $$2D^2/\lambda$$ but we need to define D value correctly.

Rayleigh distance of a single horn antenna can be calculated as shown below.
$$R=\dfrac{4A^2}{\lambda}$$

We can define D of array antenna as shown below.

[image]

Rayleigh distance of an array antenna can be calculated as shown below.
$$R=\dfrac{2(4A+A)^2}{\lambda}=\dfrac{50A^2}{\lambda}$$